# Picture overlapping program

Tags: imagemagick

I have a set of images and they overlap one another.

So if I were to put them together I would have a single larger image than any one of them, and it would show me the "full picture". It could be used for a set of images for instance, that would make a full panorama.

I can do this by hand, but then.. that's quite some work.

Is there any freely available program out there that does this?
Especially one that is free of charge and with relaxed license restrictions and works on Unix?

I have tried googling it to no avail and I have checked through ImageMagick's functionalities and haven't found this there.

The main work in a functionality like this would be to figure out first how the images need be put together in order to make a single coherent image.

Comment: Try http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php

Comment: Yeah but it must be figured out how the images need be overlayed first, that's the real work.

Comment: ok, that wasn't clear from your question. I assumed you just needed to combine a bunch of files...

Comment: ah, I see. The term you are looking for is "image stitching" Wikipedia has a nice collection of sw [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_photo_stitching_applications)

Comment: GIMP seems to support "autostitching" http://stitchpanorama.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, I'm dreaming of just a folder in which I throw images, click a button and bam, my panorama is there. Maybe I just have to write it myself.